# NSFW Soft body breast acting odd

Tags: soft-body, collision

I have been struggling all day with trying to figure out why the collision is not working on the right breast when the right arm or hand touch it.

I threw together a real quick animation and as you'll see, the left breast reacts while the right one does not.

What i didn't animate was when the left hand interacts with the right breast, it reacts correctly, and when the right hand interacts with the left breast, it reacts correctly.

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out what is causing the right arm and right breast to have no reaction.

here is the rendered out animation:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7oiXVblYNU0&feature=youtu.be

and here's the whole file in a zip so y'all can fiddle with it. It's probably something obvious that I'm just not seeing.
http://www.mediafire.com/download/nic33h5jpbn9hq0/Unfinished%2C+need+help.rar

Comment: I can't check the blend right now, but do you have a mirror modifier active? it might not be compatible with the soft body until you apply it.

Comment: no sir, mirror is already applied. only modifiers are armature, soft body, collision in that order from top to bottom.